# inheritance between two classes java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Hi I had a test today and the following question occured, could you advise me on the answer?

Assume the code of A and B comiple and run with no exceptions and no run time exceptions, also asume that that each class implements the method run only once.

What is the correct answer that will insure that the method run will run from class B.

```
A a = new B();
a.run()
```

1. Class B should implement the method run() with public access modifier.
2. Class A should implement the method run() with a private modifier.
3. Class A should implement the mothod run(String s) with a public modifier.
4. Class B should implement the method run() with a private modifier.
5. Class A should implelent run() with a public modifier.

Could you also explain?

Comment: Let's start with "what do *you* think, and why?" before we get to what we know the answer is.

Comment: This is a great example of terrible multiple choice.

Comment: Well I tried eliminating answers, so the second one is wrong as if run is with a private modifier we will get a compile error as it will not find the method at compiling time.        4. is wrong as if Im out of class B I wont see the method at all   5. is wrong same as 2 or even could do static bonding, now my options been 1 or 3 I chose 3 as I thought it would make sence it would run and then look for correct method in B

Comment: I think you have a misprint.  Options 2 and 5 seem to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question doesn't make a lot of since, but in this context I'd go with option 1. If B is assignable to A and both have implementations of run() then it can be inferred that B is a subclass of A. An instantiation of a subclass will always execute the subclass's methods.

Option 1 is the best answer from what I can tell.

Option 2 couldn't work because the calling class wouldn't have access to the method.  You'd get a compile error.

Option 3 is a completely different method signature. And it's not clear if the question is assuming an overloaded method or a replaced method.  If the former then it wouldn't matter as that method isn't being called.  If the latter, then you'd get a compile error in the calling class.

Option 4 doesn't work because you can't reduce the scope of a parent class's method.

Option 5 looks to be the same as Option 2.